# CodeIgniter SQL Server database error

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, codeigniter

I am working on a project on CodeIgniter + SQL Server.

I am getting a database error while trying to insert data to a table. But when I execute the same query directly on SQL Server, it works. The following is the error and query:

> A Database Error Occurred
>
> Error Number:
>   The statement has been terminated.
>   INSERT INTO TBL_POS_Customer (customer_name, customer_address, customer_zip, customer_city, customer_state, customer_dist_country, country_iso, country_subdivision_code, zone_code, customer_zip_code_status, customer_country_status, mainname, country_division_code) VALUES ('A.C.E.I. SPRL', '', '6001', '', '', 'BE', '', 'HT', '', '0', '1', 0, 'HT')
>   Filename: D:\Apache2.2\htdocs\POS\system\database\DB_driver.php
>   Line Number: 330

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE/ALTER TABLE ... ( ... ) TYPE=MyISAM
```

no longer works. The TYPE keyword is no longer accepted in this context.

I'm aware that TYPE= is deprecated since 4.1 and generates a warning.

```
For a quick fix, can you try to replace

TYPE=MyISAM 

with
ENGINE=MyISAM
```

Comment: The topic starter is using MsSQL, isn't he?